# Apply custom function to groupby in vaex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby, data-analysis, vaex

I want to apply some custom logic to each individual group obtained by `groupby`. It is easy to do so in pandas. How to apply some custom function to groups created by groupby in vaex?

For example, suppose I want to find the min index and max index of each group and based on that, do some operation on the rows present in that group.
Is this possible in vaex?

Answer (score 1):

I think vaex intentionally doesn't support this now, see for example this github issue https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/752.